# Nodejs: Correct Way To Return Non HTML Data To Browser?

Tags: html, http, cookies, jwt, http-headers

The users JWT gets sent to the browser as an HTTP only cookie. My question is, what is the best way to communicate display name and users database ID, etc to the browser?

I know that info can be, and is, set in the JWT payload but isn't it best practice to make that cookie (JWT) unavailable to client-side JavaScript?

I can think of two ways - setting custom response headers, or sending the data as JSON in a `<script>` element. The idea is to send this out-of-band, so to speak.

I want to stay standards compliant.

I assume the right answer is to set no-cache response header and then store that returned info in localStorage but wanted to ask...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple cookies can be sent to the browser and it is possible to selectively mark them as HTTP Only like below. Also, your server can send data/JSON in response to your browsers XHR/Fetch request.

```
let cookieArray = [];
cookieArray.push(`displayName=${displayName}`);
cookieArray.push(`id=${id}`);
cookieArray.push(`email=${email}`);
cookieArray.push(`token=${cookie}; HttpOnly`);
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookieArray);
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: Yes but do you *need* to send this information with every request? A simple JSON endpoint seems pretty reasonable here.

Comment: I think you're right and that is a very good point. In the case of JWT usage that would need to get sent in every request but the other data such as display name should be stored in local storage and can get sent to the browser via XHR/Fetch.